# How to filter a single list with objects with object inside the object?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a object which looks like this:

```
public class SchoolYear {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @BigInt
    private long schoolYearID;


    @ForeignKey(id="CountyID")
    private County county;
}
```

Each County object also have an id, and i have a Collection list of HashSet containing all SchoolYear objects.

```
Collection<SchoolYear> schoolYears = new HashSet<>();
```

I am adding each `SchoolYear` object into the `schoolYears` list. But I want to avoid adding a `SchoolYear` object if a `SchoolYear` object with an `CountyId` already in the list (so i want to check before adding to the list). So a `SchoolYear` can have different attributes, but `CountyId` always same, but i dont want multiple object of `SchoolYear` with same `CountyId`. How to do it?

Or can i filter by Java Streams? But how?

I hope my explanation is good, otherwise i can add more information if needed.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines.

```
boolean isSchoolYearPresent = schoolYears.stream()
    .filter(schoolYear -> schoolYear.getCounyId() == newSchoolyear.getCountyId())
    .findAny()
    .isPresent();
if(isSchoolYearPresent){
    //add to the collection
}
```

Comment: one should always favour `anyMatch(...)` over  `filter(...).findAny().isPresent()` in terms of performance, readability et al.